# DropDownClosed event not recognized in a toolbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I am working with wpf in VS2015.  My Window xaml includes this code snippet:

```
</ToolBarTray.Resources>
    <Style
        x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey}"
        TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger
                Property="DropDownClosed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ToolBarTray.Resources>
```

which gives me this design-time error:

```
The member "DropDownClosed" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

Is something wrong with my xaml or are combobox events not recognized in a toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

**DropDownClosed** is an event but in your xaml you handling it as a property. Use **IsDropDownOpen** and set it to false initially.

Comment: You're right - DropDownClosed is an event, not a property.  However, using IsDropDownClosed gives the design-time error "The member "IsDropDownClosed" is not recognized or is not accessible."  But based on your observation about the event, I'll see if I can find a better approach.

Comment: The property "IsDropDownClosed" does not exist , use "IsDropDownOpen" instead. Good luck